# wubi installation and standard ubuntu installation together?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, wubi

I have installed ubuntu through wubi in my machine. Now I want to install ubuntu in the normal way (maybe through live CD or bootable pen) and I don't want to uninstall my wubi ubuntu at this moment.

So finally what I want to have is Windows 7, ubuntu (wubi) and the ubuntu installed through the standard way. Will this configuration work?

Answer (score 0):

Should do.

WUBI lives entirely within the Windows partition and modifies the Windows bootloader to work. Ubuntu-proper will have its own partition and will move Windows' bootloader off as a secondary bootloader and replace it in the MBR with Grub.

To boot to Wubi you'll have to select Windows at Grub and then Ubuntu from Windows' bootloader.